# PHP convert string to "\xnn" hex

Tags: php

How can i convert string '**Hello world'** to **'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21'** using php?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work

```
function strhex($string) {
  $hexstr = unpack('H*', $string);
  return array_shift($hexstr);
}
```

**Update**

Code below what you need

```
function strtohex($string)
{
  $string = str_split($string);
  foreach($string as &$char)
    $char = "\x".dechex(ord($char));
  return implode('',$string);
}

print strtohex("[0-9A-Za-z\+/=]*");
```

Comment: almost but not quite. It gives 48656c6c6f20776f726c64. https://3v4l.org/68Cho

Comment: `echo(strhex('Hello World!'));` returns `'48656c6c6f20576f726c6421'`

Comment: bin2hex already does this natively

Comment: @Devon how can i get \x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21?? tell me

Comment: @FunnyCheese i updated my answer

Comment: Also you can use `preg_replace("/(\w{2})/", "\x$1", $text)` in last line of function

Comment: Thanks guys, that works